# Recyclerview with endless scroll, sorting and search

Tags: java, android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

My recyclerview get data from custom class and i load a little bit of data at start like this:

```
c2.addAll(categories.subList(0,totaliteminthresold));
```

categories and c2 is of same type. If i dont do this and pass categories to my adapter it loads all data in recycler view and endless scroll dont work. That is why i pass limited data at start to adapter and load more when on scroll. My recyclerview also supports action bar search and custom filters like ascending and descending order.

Is there a way to load limited data without **subList**. I tried every script on internet but most of them load limited amount of data at start like 10 or 20 items.

with **subList**, when i use my custom sorting it gives null error if i click it without scrolling down to bottom but sorting works if i load all items in recyclerview by scrolling down.

When recyclerview load i pass adapter like this:

```
 c2.addAll(categories.subList(0,totaliteminthresold));
 mAdapter = new ListAdapter(ListActivity.this, c2, recycler);
 recycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

My sorting code runs when i click button:

```
 Collections.sort(c2, new Comparator<Category>(){
  public int compare(Category s1, Category s2) {
  return s1.get_CatName().compareToIgnoreCase(s2.get_CatName());
                }
            });
  mAdapter = new ListAdapter(ListActivity.this, c2, recycler);
  recycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Is there a way to pass categories list directly to adapter at start but some how limit the adapter to not load all items.

Comment: u found any solution ?